# How to decide the minSdkVersion value in Android app

Tags: android, mobile, android-min-sdk

I know that my question is quite generic and maybe there is more than one approaches to take that decision. But I would like to listen different approaches that maybe I haven't thought since now.
Also, forgive me if stack overflow is not the right place for questions like this (since it is not technical and specific) but I strongly believe that there is not more appropriate place for this question than here. Also I am pretty sure that this subject may be interesting for many android developers here.

So, when I have to make that call, first of all

- I consider the official statistics of each distribution. So, I take a look in diagrams like [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/about/dashboards/index.html). Of course we have to keep an eye to the market and to consider very seriously what will be the future of our app one or two years later
- A second factor can be the api restrictions, but if you face this problem, sometimes is easier to decide.
- Least but not last is the specific market statistics and trends. For instance if the app is paid then you go to more specific statistics, for example Android L users spend more money on google play than the older version users.

All these thoughts became more strong after the release of [Android L](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/about/versions/android-5.0.html) which is in my opinion the most competitive version against apple. Android L encourages the use of Material Design , contains cool animations and ifrom the point of view of speed , memory management and more technical stuff is way better than the older versions (as it supposed to be).

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

All my apps are currently using api 15+.

Facebook SDK is supporting 15+ api too.

I would use api below 15 just if needed, you have more support and more easy methods to implement your app with 15+.

Answer (score 0):

Well you definitely should install Android Studio and create new project in it. There will be a dialog, which will help you choose a version, giving a percentage of covered devices worldwide.